# Unicode characters available in Android 5.0.1 but missing in 4.3

Tags: android, unicode, android-input-method, android-fonts

I'm creating a custom engineering symbol keyboard, and I'm running into a Unicode issue. I've got a Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop), and it looks like this:

[image]

Great, right? Wrong. On Android 4.3 (Jellybean), it looks like this:

[image]

So in Android 4.3, I've got 6 out of 26 symbols.

I'm fairly certain this is just because of font differences between Lollipop and Jelly Bean. Does anyone know of a way to put a custom font on an Android keyboard, or to alter system fonts in Android without rooting?

Comment: Provide your custom ttf font in `assets/fonts/your_font.ttf`. Then use it by setting is as the `typeFace` for your View/s.

Comment: The views in the keyboard? If you mean the TextViews or EditTexts in which the text would appear, that won't work. Since it's a keyboard, the only way I can touch them is by getting the InputConnection using getCurrentInputConnection, and it only allows me to push and change text, not attributes on the View itself.